# Javascript reload parent window after open email client

Tags: javascript, windows, parent, reload

I have a form with below button:

```
<input name="send_message" type="submit" value="SEND A MESSAGE" />
```

this button will trigger below php script:

```
if(isset($_POST['send_message'])){
$emails = "";

if(!empty($_POST['id'])){
    foreach($_POST['id'] as $email){
        if($emails == ""){
            $tempemail = explode("/",$email);
            $emails = $tempemail[1];
        }else{
            $tempemail = explode("/",$email);
            $emails .= ";" . $tempemail[1];
        }
    }

    if(!empty($emails)){
        echo "<script>window.location = \"mailto:me@abc.com 'recipient'?bcc=".$emails."&subject=Hello%20:%20\"</script>";

    }
```

Above script is working fine, but when the email client is open, the parent window is blank unless I refresh the page manually, I want the parent window reload when the email client is pop-up, can anyone please help? Thanks.

**Edit:**

**Solution:**

```
echo "<script>location.href = \"mailto:me@abc.com 'recipient'?bcc=".$emails."&subject=Hello%20:%20\"</script>";
echo "<script>window.location.href = "'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'"</script>";
```

Thanks Panayot Karabakalov for some idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Location reload() Method](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_loc_reload.asp) as it supported in all major browsers, or if you like may try and [alternative methods](http://www.mediacollege.com/internet/javascript/page/reload.html).

Ok, am not work with PHP, so not sure where need to insert that part, but for sure Reload() is a method/function, not property, so probably something like this:

```
if(!empty($emails)){
        echo "<script>window.location = \"mailto:me@abc.com 'recipient'?bcc=".$emails."&subject=Hello%20:%20\"</script>";
        echo "<script>window.location.reload();</script>";
    }
```

[EDIT]
Well, probably some of the PHP built-in methods to reload the page will be better, like [this](http://www.pixel2life.com/publish/tutorials/729/reloading_a_page_using_php/) for example. Also you have [mail](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php)() function that no need to reload your page.

Comment: I use `window.location.reload = "mailto:xxx"`, the email client will not bring out.

Comment: its still same blank page unless i reload by self.

Comment: Maybe the nut idea `window.location = mailto:...` is incorrect? If the user use online mail service instead of email client, like me for example, `mailto` will redirect me to gmail. Maybe there is another way to send email without changing `window.location`?

Comment: what is caused the issue is I use input type as  `type='submit'`

Comment: i put php line `header()` to refresh after `window.location = "mailto:xxx"`, page can refresh but email client never open..

Comment: You may try to call "mailto:xxx" from inside php, not js, or mail() function. I have not other ideas.